# Write same ORC data using Spark SQL and Hive, why Spark SQL file is 50% larger than hive？

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, orc

Run same sql, files generated by hive is 2.5G while files generated by spark sql is 4.1G. 
I have set spark.sql.orc.compression.codec to zlib which is what we use in hive, and set spark.sql.orc.impl to hive, my spark version is 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my question is not clear enough, because the sql is very big, more than 500 rows, and is business sensitive.

Anyway after investigation, I found the problem is caused by MR/Spark shuffle difference: MR sort in reduce while Spark does not. And sorted data is very friendly to run-length encode.